# Why does Play Store mark my application as incompatible with Galaxy Ace?

Tags: android, compatibility

I uploaded my application thinking that it support Galaxy Ace, but there should be a problem. I can't understand the reason. Where can be the problem?

Here is the badging dump of my application:

```
package: name='com.myApp' versionCode='18' versionName='1.1.0.0'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
sdkVersion:'8'
targetSdkVersion:'17'
uses-permission:'android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_TASKS'
uses-permission:'com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT'
uses-permission:'com.android.vending.BILLING'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission:'com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission:'com.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
compatible-screens:'200/160','200/240','200/320','300/120','300/160','300/240','300/320','300/480','400/120','400/160','400/240','400/320','400/480','500/120','500/160','500/240','500/320','500/480','400/213'
application-label:'MyApp'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='MyApp' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.MyApp.MainActivity'  label='MyApp' icon=''
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.wifi'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.wifi','requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, or android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
main
app-widget
other-activities
search
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'tr'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'
```

** Update:**

This is from my AndroidManifest:

```
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />


 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />

 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
```

Comment: Yes, Ace supports wifi

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of Galaxy ACE is 320 x 480 pixels, you don't have it listed on `compatible-screens` list.

Comment: Isn't Ace mdpi-normal screen? I updated the question with my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was an issue between my ACE and Play Store. ACE is Android 2.2 normally. But mine was bought as 2.3.6. Somehow Google Play Store thought that my device is still 2.2.

After playing it around "on the phone", now Play Store shows the device as compatible.